# No output from spice simulation via netlist with Xyce

Tags: terminal, simulation, circuit, pspice, netlist

I am trying to use Xyce for a project and am running into this issue. I am copying the DC sweep netlist example from the [Xyce user guide on page 39](https://xyce.sandia.gov/downloads/_assets/documents/Users_Guide.pdf) to notepad and saving it as test2c.cir.  I then copy it over into the Xyce directory and run the Xyce terminal and run the simulate command and am unable to generate any output. Is there a step I am missing to be able to run the Diode Clipper Circuit DC Sweep file? Am I saving the cir file in the right directory? It seems that the circuit "loads properly" and the syntax is fine, but I am not getting a figure output I am expecting.  I believe the issue might be that my PC doesnt have a way to open prn files, in that case, how would I fix that?

```
Diode Clipper Circuit 
** Voltage Sources 
VCC 1 0 5V 
VIN 3 0 0V 
* Analysis Command 
.DC VIN -10 15 1 
* Output 
.PRINT DC V(3) V(2) V(4) 
* Diodes 
D1 2 1 D1N3940 
D2 0 2 D1N3940 
* Resistors 
R1 2 3 1K 
R2 1 2 3.3K 
R3 2 0 3.3K 
R4 4 0 5.6K 
* Capacitor 
C1 2 4 0.47u 
.MODEL D1N3940 D( 
+ IS=4E-10 RS=.105 N=1.48 TT=8E-7 
+ CJO=1.95E-11 VJ=.4 M=.38 EG=1.36 
+ XTI=-8 KF=0 AF=1 FC=.9 
+ BV=600 IBV=1E-4) 
.END
```

[image: Error Message]

And this is the directory...

[image: directory]

UPDATE:

I changed the Analysis Command to save files as different formats (csv, raw, dat) and it still gives me the same error. Aborts because it cant open test.cir.___.  Is the problem maybe something to do with where the program directory is located?

Answer (score 0):

I was informed what a possible fix would be and it worked. The Xyce installation was in a location without admin permission (by default after serial installation).  The easiest thing to try that worked was to cd to another directory with the netlist file and run Xyce in that other directory. That generated the output file correctly!